# Enable compression while indexing data using Hive/elastic connector

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone pls share the configs in the indexer side to enable compression(gzip/deflate) for the data in transit(bulk write) in order to reduce the network consumption during indexing time.

I am able to test enabling decompress data in the ES side.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch already uses compression (default: LZ4). You can change this to deflate like this:

```
PUT my_index/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "codec": "best_compression"
  }
}
```

This is a static setting, meaning that you need to close your index first, or do it during creation.

You can read more here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @alkis, We don't want to store in ES index compressed, that will degrade the performance of elasticsearch, We want to enable compression only for the data thats gets ingested (indexed) to elasticsearch from Hadoop.